# how to scale nginx but share same volume

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm new at k8s, what's the solution when you need to scale horizontally a container in different hosts, but share the same volume, for example nginx static content.

Answer (score 1):

Create a persistent volume with ReadOnlyMany access mode. That volume can be mounted read-only by many pods. Then, create a persistent volume claim and mount that into your pods.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistentvolumeclaims

Comment: what if its not read-only? For example: others tomcat containers write static content in this shared volume

Comment: You're going to need ReadWriteMany volumes. Check the links I gave, see if the storage implementation you have supports ReadWriteMany, and any constraints it imposes.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you should rearchitect the container to not need shared storage.  In the case of something like static assets, you can `COPY` them into your image in a Dockerfile.  Another good option is to store them somewhere totally outside of Kubernetes; in AWS, you can serve them directly out of an S3 bucket, for example.

While Kubernetes lets you declare a volume is attached to a pod, you need to tell it if shared storage is attached to just one pod or to many, and if it's read/write or read-only.  There's a table in the [Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) documentation that describes the options.  If you only have options like AWSElasticBlockStore or HostPath nodes available to you, neither of these are shareable across multiple nodes.